# Crossfading between 2 audio signals / single supply opamp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, mixer

Will this circuit work? Any comments? Thanks!

Edit :
by "work" I mean I can blend the 2 audio signals in any ratio with the pot; 
it would be an OPA2132 opamp; 
input would be audio signals in the range of 0-3.3v

[image: my diagram]

it seems even this circuit would work? [image]

Comment: What is your definition of "work"? and what opamp are you using there? and what signals are on the input side?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Question edited.

Comment: Please attantion to your diagram of output. You need dual supply here because its swing include negative cycles.

Comment: I guess with both inputs swinging between 0-3.3v with roughly 1.6v center. The input of the final opamp would never be negative?

Comment: If your sure about the input dc voltages then this circuit seems to work single supply reasonably.

Comment: @Zilaihong : Your output connection is wrong. Connect Load directly to op-amp output and after that use decoupling Capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

There are simpler circuits like this one: -

[image]

And I've posted it for two reasons, 1) to show the decoupling capacitors that must be fitted and 2) to explain that your circuit has certain benefits that may not be that obvious.

You circuit does not rely on the signal sources being low impedance - if the pot is totally at one end of its travel it will 100% attenuate one signal whereas the simplified circuit won't do that if the output impedances of the signal sources are not zero.

If you are expecting unity gain, then you ought to figure out the proper value of feedback resistor - with your circuit's pot at one end, the other channel will suffer a fair amount of attenuation but this can be easily remedied however you need to state what value your pot has. I'd go for your circuit over my example.

Comment: Thank you! I've edited my question post with a new diagram, please check it, I want to use a 10k pot.

Comment: I wouldn't edit your question to reflect what answers have said - this makes my answer look stupid - please do consider rolling back your question to the original version that I answered.

Comment: If you are using a 10k pot then it would be sensible to consider a 33k feedback resistor.

Comment: Sorry I've rolled it back. 1 channel of signal is from an opamp buffer, the other directly from DAC, with a dual opamp chip I can buffer the DAC signal so I think your circuit would be a better option?

Comment: With decent low impedance sources my circuit is simpler - that's the only benefit. Whether you should buffer the dac depends on the dac!

Comment: @Zilaihong the gain of this circuit is variable according to POT adjustment. It's a bug in the circuit.

Comment: Anyway I have one opamp left unused on the chip so let me buffer the DAC and go with your circuit. Any comments on the decoupling cap value? would 0.1uf be enough? Thanks!

Comment: @HOPE oh I see, it effectively changes the Rin on the opamp... thanks for notice!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is OK, but the DC biasing is messed up.  The DC level of R3 should be decoupled from the opamp input.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using such a circuit as below. first section is a inverting unity gain op-amp. then a voltage divider. and finally a voltage subtract circuit.

Vou = Input2 + (Input1/K)

which K is the constant of pot R3.

Advantages of this circuit :

1. No Loading effect on the both input voltages.
2. Control Gain of each Input voltage independently.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFrEnd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you, but want I want to do is just crossfading between 2 inputs. and I guess your circuit would require split supply?

Comment: Yes besides the exact controlling over gains, you need dual supply voltage sources like 7805 and 7905.

Comment: thanks, but I only have positive supply so I would need a circuit to work with it. Please check this circuit : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194357/audio-blend-circuit-emitter-follower

Comment: Well I do, it seems an considerable circuit.But using an op-amp give you more S/N ratio than single transistors. If you prefer using single supply, then exact value of combination gain is loses. But I don't think it's too important to you.

Comment: thanks! I have tried a very simple circuit with a simulation software and it seems it would work?! I have uploaded the pic in the question.

Comment: @Zilaihong. A thing about your new circuit: as I see, you're not removing dc input of signals, nor biasing them with a static dc voltage. In real tests, this is very important for you, becuse your sources may be Zero DC or have different DC values and this will ruin your circuit.

Comment: yes I am not removing DC because I only have single supply on the opamps so I need to keep the swing all in positive range. One thing I am certain is the inputs, they are all within 0-3.3v range. and I can have up to 9v supply on the opamp so it can provide enough headroom. Thank you very much for bearing with a novice like me.