# audio blend circuit / emitter follower

Tags: transistors, emitter-follower

This diagram is found online. 
My input would be audio signal in 0-3.3v range. 
 
Will it work under 9v with 2N3904 or BC54x transistors? 
 
Does it need component value adjustment while operating under 9v / 5v? 
What does Rt means at the left bottom corner? 
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If your input voltages are high enough, CC configuration seems good, otherwise it's better to use a CE configuration for your transistors.

Answer (score 1):

For selecting proper value of resistors you should have at least two option : Vce_saturation and Vbe_on.  Lets assume your VCC=5 volt , Vbe_on = 0.7 volt and Vce_sat=0.2 volt.

For Maximum output swing we should set Ve voltage to :

Ve = (VCC - Vce_sat) / 2 
Ve = (5-0.2) / 2 = 2.4 volt.

So Vb = Ve + 0.7volt = 3.1 Volt.

Then we need to set Rb1 and Rb2 to achieve this voltage.

Vb = ( Rb2 / (Rb2+ Rb1) ) * VCC

Rb1/Rb2 = VCC/Vb - 1 = 0.61

Using Normal values for resistors : Rb1 = 33K and Rb2 = 56K .

assuming Ie = 1 mA : Re = Ve / Ie = 2.4K . that Using a 2.2K resistor is sufficient.

And as you now Voltage gain of CC configuration is about unity.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed explaination. but these is way beyond my electric novice knowledge. Will some opamp buffers and a passive mixing stage work? like this new circuit diagram in this thread http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/194180/crossfading-between-2-audio-signals-single-supply-opamp-circuit

Comment: I see your new design. Except your Loading, I see nothing wrong about your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the data sheet for your transistors. Look for maximum rated voltages for the collector. And stay below that with your battery.

Rt means input impedance (resistance, total).

Its rather simplistic, and you will not get a complete range between full dry and full wet, the ratio being dependant on the value of the pot vs the emitter resistance. I would advise ac coupling the output With another cap

You may need to adjust the resistor values.